# Android - How to add Notification Counter on the right above of ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, notifications, counter

I want to have an app with similar notification counter on the right side of the Imageview: here is the photo of my layout:

[image: MyPhoto.png]

I want to have such Notification Counter:

[image: OriginalApp.png]

Here is my activity_menu layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="datasite.com.konnex.Menu"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3fc0ea">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/lg1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp" />

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

      <GridLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:columnCount="2">
         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="90dp"
             android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:src="@drawable/cases"
             android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
             android:id="@+id/img_cases"/>
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="90dp"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:src="@drawable/invoices"
              android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="90dp"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:src="@drawable/announcement"
              android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="90dp"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:src="@drawable/users"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
          <ImageView
               android:layout_width="90dp"
               android:layout_height="90dp"
               android:src="@drawable/document"
              android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="90dp"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:src="@drawable/meetings"
              android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

      </GridLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fffafa"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/dark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my menu.java class:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

            private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                    = new 

BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_location:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_phone:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

            }
    }
```

Please help to find solution to this problem. I have searched many answers but haven't found the solution specific to my case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try this [android-viewbadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your every ImageView in FrameLayout like this.

```
<GridLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:columnCount="2">
      <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="90dp"
          android:layout_height="90dp">
          <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@drawable/cases"/>
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="1"
             android:background="@android:color/red"
             android:layout_gravity="top|end"/>
      </FrameLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fc0505"
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Avinash? it is working with textview, but can't get set badge(. can you please help to do that

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your images inside `GridLayout` with `RelativeLayout` and put the notificaton indicators inside RelativeLayout.
Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="90dp"
     android:layout_height="90dp">
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/cases"
     android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
     android:id="@+id/img_cases"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#FF0000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and you can update them via

```
GridLayout gridLayout.... 
TextView item1 = (TextView) gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.item1);
item1.setText("3"); // 3 notifications
```

Comment: Thanks helped with textview. but how to make a badge counter on the above of the icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Constraint layout as follows :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list_24px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@string/filter"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/filter"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Add a Drawable resource file for adding background to counter as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#DD2C00" />
            <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF" android:width="1dp" />
            <size
                android:height="15dp"
                android:width="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```